# Change view in a page view controller when button is pressed in one of the controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` connected to three view controllers

[image]

And three classes for each `UIViewController`

[image]

When the "Take Photo" button is pushed, the third view should slide into view. When "Choose From Library" is pushed the first view controller should slide into view.

I have 3 classes controlling each `UIViewController` and one class that controls the pages in the storyboard. Here is the **pageViewController.m**

```
@implementation pageViewController

{
NSArray *myViewControllers;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];    

  self.delegate = self;
  self.dataSource = self;

  UIViewController *p1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"one"];
  UIViewController *p2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"two"];
  UIViewController *p3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"three"];


  myViewControllers = @[p1, p2, p3];
  pageTwoViewController *ptvc = [[pageTwoViewController alloc] init];
  ptvc.publicViewControllers = myViewControllers;

  [self setViewControllers:@[p2] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

The app has already been programmed to switch views when flicking to the left or right.

I have the buttons linked to their respecting classes but I don't know how to switch visible view controllers via the buttons. How can I change the visible `UIViewController` when one of buttons is pushed on the second view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call "setViewControllers" again to switch to a different view controller. So, for example, if you wanted to move to "p1", use something like this:

```
// grab a reference out of your existing NSArray
UIViewController *newVC = self.myViewControllers[0];
[self setViewControllers:@[newVC] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Using "animated:YES" will cause the same slide as if the user navigated manually. Adjust the "direction" based on whether you are jumping forward or backwards.

To communicate between your child view controllers and their parent, use a delegate. First, declare a delegate in your parent view controller's header, such as this:

```
@protocol PhotoSourceDelegate <NSObject>
  - (void)takePhoto;
  - (void)chooseFromLibrary;
@end
```

Update your parent view controller to implement this delegate:

```
@interface pageViewController : UIPageViewController <PhotoSourceDelegate>
@end

@implementation pageViewController
...
#pragma mark - PhotoSourceDelegate
- (void)takePhoto {
  // call "setViewController" to display "take photo" view controller;
}

- (void)chooseFromLibrary {
  // call "setViewController" to display "choose from library" view controller;
}
```

Within the header of the view controller which shows the "Take Photo" and "Choose From Library" buttons (p2?), add a property to hold a reference to the delegate:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<PhotoSourceDelegate> delegate;
```

When you instantiate this controller, be sure to set its delegate:

```
UIViewController *p2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"two"];
p2.delegate = self;
```

Finally, within that same view controller, when your "Take Photo" button is pressed, call the delegate like this:

```
if (self.delegate != nil) {
  [self.delegate takePhoto];
}
```

And when your "Choose From Library" button is pressed, call the delegate like this:

```
if (self.delegate != nil) {
  [self.delegate chooseFromLibrary];
}
```

The use of delegates is very common in iOS, so a quick search will turn up quite a few tutorials if/when you're ready to get a better understanding.

Comment: My array of views is located in a parent view controller separate from the view controller (p2) that owns the button that I want to change views. I would need p2 to have access to the parent view controller's array of view controllers so the view could be changed. How could I do that?

Comment: Then use a delegate to communicate from your p1/p2/p3 view controllers back to your parent view controller, which in turn navigates to the appropriate view.

Comment: This is what I've been trying to do for a couple hours now, ha. Would you mind explaining how I could make this delegate?

Comment: Update answer with info on using a delegate for communicating between view controllers.

Comment: Thanks, this has been really helpful but I am having one problem with setting p2's delegate. I'm trying to set it when it is initially instantiated in the parent view controller but it returns an error. Should I be setting it's delegate elsewhere?

Comment: No, immediately after instantiating is fine. You didn't mention what error was thrown, so I can only guess what the problem might be. I see in my answer that I didn't mention that your parent view controller needs to reference the PhotoSourceDelegate protocol in its declaration. I will update the answer with that info.

Comment: The error it is throwing is "Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'" when i set p2's delegate to `self`